# What is the most concise and morally correct way to express this operation?

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices. Define $f(A, B)$ as follows. If $X=f(A, B)$ then $X_{i,j} = \sum_{t=1}^k (A_{i,t} - B_{t, j})^2$

Assuming $A$ has dimensions $m\times k$ and $B$ has dimensions $k\times n$, this is well-defined. It is also easy to express in pseudocode. But I am having trouble figuring out how to write it elegantly in terms of matrix operations.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_i$ denote the $i^{th}$ row of matrix $A$ and similarly for $B^\top$. Then
$$
X_{ij}:=\|A_i-(B^\top)_j\|^2.
$$
Note that this operation is far from being linear in the matrix inputs $A$ and $B$, so there is no simple expression in terms of standard matrix operations.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of this expression actually, but I was wondering if there was some "non-pointwise" way to write it. I should have made the question more clear.